# Mule SOAP WS-Security configuration key value

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I was testing below SOAP web service security example.
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/SOAP+Web+Service+Security+Example
Here in the soap component configuration, key value pair is action and UsernameToken TimeStamp. In Enabling WS-Security it is mentioned that key value are constant of WSHandlerContant class. But if instead of UsernameToken i use the constant variable USERNAME_TOKEN of WSHandlerContant class i am getting errors. 
Can anyone tell me where i can find possible value of key value for SOAP security.
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Enabling+WS-Security
http://people.apache.org/~coheigea/stage/wss4j/1.5.5/site/apidocs/org/apache/ws/security/handler/WSHandlerConstants.html#PW_CALLBACK_CLASS

Answer (score 0):

Below are the contant field values that we can use in SOAP Security configuration.

http://people.apache.org/~coheigea/stage/wss4j/1.5.5/site/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandlerConstants.RECEIVE